# cakePHP 3: How to do an association by intersecting categories

Tags: associations, cakephp-3.x

Ok, sorry for the convoluted subject here - I am having a hard time describing this problem.

In CakePHP 3.x I have this:

Articles Table
Parts Table
Categories Table

Articles belongsToMany Categories
Parts belongsToMany Categories

In Parts I would like to setup an association called filteredArticles that fetches articles, which have the same categories as the Part.

I have looked into using a custom finder like this:

```
$this->hasMany('filteredArticles',[
    'className' => 'Articles',
    'finder' => 'filtered'
]);
```

That doesn't seem to work for me though, as the finder would have to be in the Articles Table and thus cannot reference the categories of the part.

I hope this makes sense and that someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: Wouldn't that be the case by default, given that `Parts` and `Articles` are only indirectly associated via `Categories`? ie containing `Categories.Articles` would naturally only return those `Articles` that belong to the same category as `Parts`.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. I do this: ->contain('Categories' => ['Articles'])
But that gets me any Article that shares any Category with the Part. What I need is actually only the articles that shares all Categories. Does that make sense?